# Call IBAction auto execute in other method

Tags: ios

I have IBAction and Method. My purpose I want to call IBAction of buttonSignIn into method getData. In this case I want this application auto login without typing username and password, but it didn't work. Here is my code below:

```
-(void)storeData
{
    NSString *usr = [_txtUsername stringValue];
    NSString *pwd = [_txtPwd stringValue];
    
    NSUserDefaults *store = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [store setObject:usr forKey:@"usrname"];
    [store setObject:pwd forKey:@"usrpwd"];
    
    [store synchronize];
}

-(void)getData
{  
    if ([_remCheckbox state] == NSOnState)
    {
        NSUserDefaults *store = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        
        NSString *un = [store objectForKey:@"usrname"];
        NSString *pw = [store objectForKey:@"usrpwd"];
        
        _txtUsername.stringValue = un;
        _txtPwd.stringValue = pw;
        
        //call event IBAction
        [self buttonSignIn:self];
        
    }  
}

- (IBAction)buttonSignIn:(id)sender
{
    [self storeData];
    
    //Code for login suppose to work here
    .........
    ......... 
}
```

I use [self buttonSignIn:self]; but it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: [self buttonSignIn:self] should call the method "buttonSignIn". What is your debug information?

Comment: when I debug it step to buttonSignIn but interface it not work (not login) but debug is work fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "debug is work fine"? if it fires the method buttonSignIn, then it's not the problem of [self buttonSignIn:self]

Comment: yeah now I found the problem, it is because I use [self buttonSignIn:self];

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```objc
[self buttonSignIn:nil];
```

You can also use `performSelectorOnMainThread:`.

If you want to use `self` to carry out your call then pass `nil` as parameter instead of `self`.

i.e

```objc
[self buttonSignIn:nil];
```

Comment: you can use this..

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(buttonSignIn:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: please click answer was useful to you if it has helped you.